# Forcing an index in oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization, indexing

I have a query joining lots of fields.  For some strange reason the index for one table is not being used at all( I use the index key clearly), instead it is doing a FULL table scan.  I would like to force the index.  We used to do optimizer hints in sybase.  Is there a similar hint available in oracle?
For example, in sybase to join tables a, b, c and use myindex in table a, I would do :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM     a(INDEX myindex),
         b,
         c
WHERE    a.field1 = b.field1
AND      b.field1 = c.field1
```

Question is how do I do this in oracle.
Thanks
Saro

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405

Comment: Could you post the query plan ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to try and outsmart the query optimizer. A short explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358137/oracle-full-text-search-with-condition/7379753#7379753

Comment: I've definitely seen situations where Oracle chose a full table scan when an index was more efficient, and vice versa. The first situation usually arose when selecting from a large table where most of the rows would *not* be selected, and the second situation usually arose when selecting from a large table where most of the rows *would* be selected.

Comment: @Vanessa perhaps you needed to generate stats to handle the skewed distribution of data see: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:707586567563 rather than use a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a hint like that in Oracle. It looks something like this:

```
select /*+ index(a my_index) */ from a
```

Comment: You need the tablespec (see the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405)); the index name is optional if you want to suggest Oracle uses an index but don't want to specify which one. So it should be `INDEX(a my_index)`. And if the table has an alias in the query, you have to use the alias as the tablespec.

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying I should do something like this:
SELECT /*+ index(a my_index) */ , a.* FROM     a(INDEX myindex),          
  b,          
  c 
WHERE    a.field1 = b.field1 
AND      b.field1 = c.field1

Comment: @Saro - no: `SELECT /*+ index(a my_index) */ a.* FROM a, b, c WHERE a.field1 = b.field1 AND b.field1 = c.field1`. (Preferably with ANSI joins, but that's another subject...)