# SQL Server/Oracle calling specifix Index

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The below was the Database(SQL Server/Oracle) question asked by Interviewer to me.

> **How do i call a specific index In case if i have multiple indexes?**

I have no idea on it. I searched in google but failed.

Comment: Index hints. That's it. One question per post.

Comment: These are two questions and so must be two posts.  Especially as they're not related to each other, and so rreally demand separate answers.

Comment: @ta.speot.is now only 1 question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing an index in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418860/forcing-an-index-in-oracle)

Comment: Refer Table Hints here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(v=sql.105).aspx. Apply Table Hint  like `OPTION (TABLE HINT ( e, INDEX( IX_Index_Name) , NOLOCK, FORCESEEK ))`

Answer (score 2):

You can provide [hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm) to the optimiser.

Index hints look like this:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(<table name> <index name> <optional free text comment> */ field1, field2...
```

Example:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(patients sex_index) use sex_index because there are few
   male patients  */ name, height, weight
FROM patients
WHERE sex = 'm';
```

Comment: Can you give some scenario and elaborate it. showing me like a commented code. :( i am confusing

Comment: I have given an example telling you the syntax. If you add a specific SQL query and the name and table for the index you wish to use I can show you how to add the hint.